# If the weighted $L^p$ norm of a measurable function is finite, is the weighted $L^p$ norm of the antiderivative also finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function 
such that 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f|^p e^{-x^2} \,dx  < \infty. $$
Define $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be 
$$ g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(x^{\prime}) d x^{\prime}.$$
Is it necessarily true that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g|^p e^{-x^2} \,dx  < \infty $$
?

More generally, suppose $f \colon \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is 
a measurable function
such that 
$$ \int |f|^p e^{-(x_1^2 + \ldots + x_m^2)} \,dx_1 \ldots dx_m  < \infty. $$
and $g \colon \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined to be 
$$ g(x_1, x_2, .., x_m) = \int_{0}^{x_1} f(x_1^{\prime}, x_2, \ldots, x_m) \,d x_1^{\prime}.$$

Is it necessarily true that 
$$\int |g|^p e^{-(x_1^2 + \ldots x_m^2)} \,dx_1 \ldots dx_m  < \infty $$
?

Answer (score 0):

There are weighted version of Hardy's inequality, for instance [page 3](http://books.google.fr/books?id=4SqMH8Drl40C&pg=PA11&hl=fr&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) (it works for $p\gt 1$).

For general $m$, we can use an induction argument.

Comment: It seems the answer to my question should be no......take $ f(x) = \frac{e^{x^2}}{1+x^2}$. I think someone gave this answer and then deleted it.

Comment: How do you prove the corresponding integral for he primitive diverges? // I can see the deleted answers, and the only one was of mine.

Comment: I agree, its not clear the corresponding integral for the primitive diverges. Are you saying that using Hardy's inequality (or some variant of it), we can show it converges?

Comment: Yes, it seems the link I gave gives some conditions on the weight in order to map $L^p$ to $L^p$.